# Preview content on site in Sanity not working

Tags: sanity

I'm following the Sanity docs on how to add a [content preview](https://www.sanity.io/docs/preview-content-on-site). After updating the `sanity.json` and adding a `resolveProductionUrl.js` file according to docs I should be able to see a menu item in context menu:

[image]

But it's not happening. Interestingly enough If I add a console log to a `resolveProductionUrl.js` I can see it on the browser console - meaning that this function is getting called.

This is what I see:

[image]

Comment: Have the same issue, but the answer below with `@sanity/production-preview` seems to refer to some V2 package, anyone knows how to tackle this problem in V3, like described [here](https://www.sanity.io/docs/previewing-content-in-sanity-studio)?  I never see a link to the productionUrl in my studio, and also I don't know where exactly to look since the UI in the screenshot doesnt look familiar?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue while following along using Sanity's [Preview content on site](https://www.sanity.io/docs/preview-content-on-site) article.

There were three things I had to do after following their article in order to get it to work:

1. I had do add this line in `sanity.json` under `plugins`
   add highlighting to the line:

```
  "plugins": [
    ...
    "@sanity/production-preview"
  ],
```

(I didn't add this line to my `sanity.json` file on the first attempt. The article did not highlight that line, so looks like its just provided as context since the `parts` entry is highlighted.)

2. I also had to update `resolveProductionUrl.js` to use `document._id` instead of `document.slug.current` as `slug` is undefined for me and it was throwing errors in the console (and not showing the menu item).
3. I had to completely stop the site and re-run `sanity start` to get it to be picked up locally.